# Spring Boot Admin, client registration results in bad request

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am going to register my spring boot application to `spring-boot-admin` server.

Here is my `SpringBootAdminApplication.java`

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableAdminServer
public class SpringBootAdminApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootAdminApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-example</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and `application.properties`

```
server.port = 8080
```

Server is running now:

[image]

Now, in client side:

properties:

```
spring.boot.admin.url=http://localhost:8080
info.version=@project.version@
spring.application.name=rest-module
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But, when i run the spring boot from client, i get this error:

```
Created POST request for "http://localhost:8080/api/applications"
Setting request Accept header to [application/json, application/json, application/*+json, application/*+json]

Writing [Application [id=null, name=rest-module, managementUrl=http://Hayatloo-PC:8082, healthUrl=http://Hayatloo-PC:8082/health, serviceUrl=http://Hayatloo-PC:8082]] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@1637320b]
 Failed to register application as Application [id=null, name=rest-module, managementUrl=http://Hayatloo-PC:8082, healthUrl=http://Hayatloo-PC:8082/health, serviceUrl=http://Hayatloo-PC:8082] at spring-boot-admin (http://localhost:8080/api/applications): 400 Bad Request
```

Why `id=null` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You messed up the versions. Try to update the client and  server to the same versions. We try too keep em compatible but from 1.0.x to 1.3.x you have no chance.
Btw current version is 1.3.2.

Additional you are using the sample as dependency. This indeed works, but I wouldn't recommend it. You better setup your server as described in the guide. http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/1.3.2/

Comment: Thanks for answer, but when i use the guide dependencies, i get this errro on server side:
`Error processing condition on de.codecentric.boot.admin.config.HazelcastStoreConfiguration.applicationStore`
`IllegalArgumentException: @ConditionalOnMissingBean annotations must specify at least one bean (type, name or annotation)`

Comment: Are you using the latest spring boot?

Comment: My spring boot version is `1.2.6.RELEASE`

Comment: either you downgrade to a spring boot admin 1.2.x or you update your spring boot to 1.3.x

Comment: and spring-boot-starter version is `1.3.1.RELEASE`